# removing and putting attribute for the select box returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the 'disabled' and 'selected' property to false and then put 'selected' and 'disabled' property to the first option of the select box. Below is my code

my html

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <!-- input fields -->
    <input name="test1 value="test 2" required/>
    <input name="test2 value="test 3" required/>
    <input name="test3 value="test 4" required/>
    <!-- select fields -->
    <select name="server_type">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select option</option>
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <!-- select fields -->
    <select name="server_ip_type">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select option</option>
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and my script

```
 $("form").submit(function(e){
    //lets clear the input fields
    $("input", this).each(function(){
        $(this).val(""); 
    });
    //lets reset the select box
    $("select option", this).each(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled selected", false);
    });
    $("select[name='server_type'] option:first-child, select[name='server_ip_type'] option:first-child").attr("disabled selected", true);
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

at first, what im trying is to loop to each input fields within the form and clear the each value, second, I intend to loop to each option of each select tag (i have 2 select tag) and set the 'selected' and 'disabled' property of each option of each select tag to false and then third, I set the 'disabled' and 'selected' property of each select tag of there each first option tag to true but sadly it doesnt work and It returns me this error

> Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'disabled selected' is not a valid attribute name.

any ideas, help, suggestion, recommendation, clues will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
$("select option", this).attr({
    disabled: false,
    selected: false
})
```

Comment: not working when i tried to put "this" but its working without "this", any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon the above fiddle seems to be working.. can you recreate the issue in it

Comment: yes its working when removing but i mean when setting up the disabled and selected attribute to true to each first option of each select tag

Answer (score 0):

You should use `removeAttr`

```
$(this).removeAttr("disabled selected");
```

**OR**

```
$(this).prop({
    "disabled": false,
    "selected": false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem  `attr("disabled selected", false);` you should use

```
attr("disabled", false);
attr("selected", false);
```

` [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to attr()